# Command not found when comparing string

Tags: shell

I have this script

```
#!/bin/sh        
if [ $# -ne 3 ] ; then
            echo "param 1, param2, and A or B "
            exit 1;

    elif [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
                    if [$3 = "A"] ; then
                                    echo "A"
                    elif [$3 = "B"]; then
                                    echo "B"
                    fi

fi
```

It is basically checking if param 3 is A or B, and do echo. But it returns:

```
./test.sh: line 6: [A: command not found
./test.sh: line 8: [A: command not found
```

I tried to use `-eq` for comparison, but it still does not work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You do not need the `elif [ $# -eq 3 ]; then` line as you know that `$#` is 3 as of your 1st test.  You could then avoid one level of indent and a `fi` replacing `if [$3 = "A"] ; then` by `elif [$3 = "A"] ; then`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm sure this has come up before, but -- `[` is actually a command. You need a space after the `[` in order for the shell to find it.

Comment: thank you, i will accept this after 9 mins (as stack overflow does not allow me yet to accept )

Comment: The reason that you need the space is that the shell tokenizes the line by splitting it up wherever there are one or more spaces and/or tabs. If you don't have a space after the [ then it isn't a separate token. Similar for ] although the test command ignores that one, but it will interfere with the comparisons if there is no space before it